# Closing the Stack Snippet editor doesn't refocus the textarea

Tags: bug, asking-questions, code-formatting, editor, stack-snippets

To reproduce:

1. Click [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and focus the question body `textarea`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
3. Hit the `X` and confirm that you do not want to "abandon any changes."
4. Immediately press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> again.
5. No snippet editor.

If you again focus the question body `textarea`, the snippet editor will reopen. I am experiencing this issue in Chrome 38.

I propose the focus be returned to the `textarea` when the snippet editor is closed.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that the Ctrl+M shortcut only works if the focus is on the question body textarea. If you close the window, then the focus is not there so the shortcut key won't work. The button will still work.

Not sure if this is by design or not, but it explains it at least.